# Possible to use cypress for e2e with embedded jxbrowser?

Tags: selenium, testing, cypress, jxbrowser

I've recently found and fallen in love with Cypress for e2e testing, much more so than Selenium, but there's a catch: our web app will actually be within jxbrowser, inside a java app.  Whatever e2e framework we choose has to be able to run all the tests within jxbrowser inside of this embedded application (hence why we originally looked at selenium, because of the remote driver)

Is it possible to get this working? We absolutely need the embedded jxbrowser tests (Cots integration, can't get around it), and I'd hate to have to fall back to selenium.

Comment: You should create a ProofOfConcept.

Comment: What have you actually tried so far? What were your specific problems?

Comment: I was actually trying to investigate the feasibility of bashing my head against this, and trying to see if anyone had done this, or done something similar so that I could guide my initial POC steps. We unfortunately don't have many cycles to burn on trying this testing out (even though this SHOULD be important....). But fair enough, I'll come back to this question once ive delved more into the weeds on it.

Comment: Hi, I'm from the dev team. We are currently working on a feature to allow spawning custom browsers, but I would highly advise against trying to implement this yourself. I would say the timeline for custom browsers is next year.

Comment: Also, could you elaborate on why testing inside the Java app is important? Do you have Java apis your application uses? Do you want to ensure the JavaScript can run properly, or do you care about possible css visual differences from chrome?

Comment: @bkucera It's actually important for us because the systems for seeing information and pulling data etc live inside a cots system, and it has a built in workflow system that is far, far too complicated to stub or mock, and the end state for this app is that users will see this react app inside of the java app, and there's alot of integration between the two. On top of that, soon, the cots layer that we're extending knows if it's running inside the java app or if it's outside, and with a future upgrade coming soon, ..

Comment: ...the cots application will not allow a react app to work at all outside of being instantiated inside the java app.  So our e2e works for now, but once that upgrade occurs, we won't be able to even run the app on its own.

Comment: Unfortunately, we did not test JxBrowser with Cypress. Having looked through Cypress documentation, it seems like it is possible to make Cypress work with JxBrowser:

1) You will need to create an executable file that will run JxBrowser and parse the arguments in order to understand which URL Cypress asks to open.
2) Then you will need to configure Cypress to launch JxBrowser executable: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/launching-browsers.html#Launching-by-a-path